# how to increase the width of date field in admin grid

Tags: adminhtml, css, grid

How to increase the width of date field in admin grid while searching the value is cut-off.
Please See the image below[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width for the date inputs is determined by this selector in `boxes.css`.

```
.grid tr.filter .range input
```

It is set to `50px!important`.
You need to edit that and increase the value.
Of course, don't edit a core file.
[Create your own admin theme](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates) and clone the file `boxes.css` in your new theme and change the value there.
For me a value of about `61px` seams right.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/24109/243) already explained, the CSS comes from `boxes.css`, but the best way to adjust CSS in an own admin theme is, using `custom.css`. Magento looks for this file if you are in the admin area, but the default admin theme does not contain it, so you can create it and do not need to copy anything from the default theme.

For the definition, see in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml`:

```
            <action method="addCss"><name>reset.css</name></action>
            <action method="addCss"><name>boxes.css</name></action>
            <action method="addCss"><name>custom.css</name></action>
```

Since `custom.css` is loaded after `boxes.css`, this definition will override the existing one:

```
.grid tr.filter .range input {
    width: 100px;
}
```